# Microsoft Bot (webchat channel): 500 Internal Server error: failed to send message

Tags: botframework, chatbot

We have embedded a Bot on a web page through the web chat channel, if the Bot is **idle** for 10 minutes or so and then a question is asked, the Bot does not respond to it, however when the same question is asked again immediately it responds as expected.

On investigating the network capture, we observed the response received when the question was asked for the first time was 500: Internal Server Error with message as "failed to send message"

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the bot in Azure? If so, make sure you have "AlwaysOn" enabled; otherwise the web app will be unloaded if it's idle for a period of time. Check [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1343) for a similar problem.

> **Always On**. By default, web apps are unloaded if they are idle for some period of time. This lets the system conserve resources. In Basic or Standard mode, you can enable Always On to keep the app loaded all the time. If your app runs continuous web jobs, you should enable Always On, or the web jobs may not run reliably.

You can read more about the web sites configuration [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/).