# Initialize conversation by service

Tags: c#, botframework

I am relatively new in timer services. 
So, i want to generally ask for an example or pseudo code how to initialize conversation with user using microsoft bot framework ?

Idea :

In my web site with users and events i want to notify user when his/her event will take time. 
For example if he/her follows an event, send notification as conversation on facebook before the event starts or something like that.

I made authentication for users on my bot. This is my next step.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank  you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look to the [AlarmBot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AlarmBot) sample. It shows an scenario pretty similar to yours. Is a complex sample so take the time to understand all the pieces.

Additionally, you can take a look to this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botFramework-proactiveMessages), where you will find simpler examples on how to send proactive messages.

Comment: Can i store user and bot properties when user authenticate to bot in my database and later initialize conversation ? What do you think ? 
Btw, thank you very much for your answers. You always post useful things !

Comment: Sure; it should be possible.  As long as you have the user/bot ids you should be able to do that... https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-CreateNewConversation

Comment: I made this. It initializes conversations with multiple users. 
But i realized that on the microsoft end point bot "sleeps". 
If you don't write to bot nothing, the service not works.
If you constantly write to bot everything is okey.

Some idea why this is happening ?

Comment: A u running in Azure? If so, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39852390/microsoft-bot-webchat-channel-500-internal-server-error-failed-to-send-messa/39853068#39853068

Comment: I moved my bot to iis. Any idea ? Btw : i see that and up voted.