# How to start a conversation with a Facebook bot from a webpage?

Tags: botframework, facebook-chatbot

The objective I have is to start a conversation with a bot on Facebook, but open it from our website.

I want to know how to link the bot page to a button and start a conversation in a new tab or a similar option.
Just to clarify I dont want to have an embedded chat, I want to chat with the bot on the Facebook page.

Thanks.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996961/initialize-conversation-by-service) out. Btw i think this thread is duplicate...

Comment: I don't think that's what I asked but its solved at the same Facebook Help Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution to my problem. Its a button, it can make the bot start a conversation with you sending something (I don't know yet) that makes the bot answer with a Null LUIS intent. The other thing that works is a button that opens a new chat with the bot on Messenger.

Facebook help page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/plugin-reference/send-to-messenger

Github of a valid method: https://github.com/fbsamples/messenger-platform-samples/tree/master/node