# Bot framework facebook messenger not always responding

Tags: c#, azure, bots, botframework, messenger

I've made a bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework (C#) and published it on Azure.
It works perfectly fine on an emulator and on Skype. But on Facebook Messenger, it seems like sometimes, it doesn't receive the message properly (even though no error is shown) sent by the user but retyping the message several times seems to wake it up.

Anyone ever had this issue or have an idea what's happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39852390/microsoft-bot-webchat-channel-500-internal-server-error-failed-to-send-messa/39853068?s=6|2.0992#39853068

Comment: No really no... I saw that post a week ago and my azure is set "Always On".
Plus, my problem appears only on Facebook Messenger, not any other platforms. So it makes me think that my Azure config is fine.

Comment: Furthermore, it happens randomly on any messages, not only when you haven't use the bot for a while.

Comment: do you see any error message in the bot framework portal, under the facebook messenger channel?

Comment: Unfortunately, none.

Comment: Could you add logging in your bot implementation in the very begging of the api/messages endpoint and see if you get all calls from the bot framework service on each message from Facebook?

Comment: We just did it, thanks for the advice.
We only get the calls for the messages that the bot answers. Nothing seems to react for the messages that are ignored. It seems to happen more frequently during our "FormFlow".

Comment: I just depublished the bot from Facebook and now it works perfectly fine!
Still though, I will need to publish it in some point in the future...

Comment: Check on the FB app dashboard in the messenger webhooks there is a button to displays errors in webhooks.