# Set up an azure botframework application to be 'always on'

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-functions

When I configure a new azure bot service application on Azure, it creates it as a consumption pricing tier application.  This seems to possibly be causing issues on cold starts where the application takes quite a long time (in comparison to a running application) to respond.

I would like to configure the application to use a resource group that is on an basic plan so that I can make it 'always on'.

Is there a setting I am missing or is this just not possible at this time?

Edit:  I am OK with paying for the ability to enable "Always On" like I can with the typical Azure Function/web apps.  At this point I do not see a way to configure a bot application to allow it to be anything but a consumption based application.

Edit2: clarified that this is an azure bot service application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bot responses with lag after certain time of non-use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42508817/bot-responses-with-lag-after-certain-time-of-non-use)

Comment: I'm going to investigate this more, and get back to you.  ABS bots should be   provisionable into an App Service plan.  I've been unable to find it thus far.

Comment: You'll need to setup a VM to host the Azure Function app as Always On.  Please see edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating an SDK bot, or an `Azure Bot Service` bot?  SDK bots are just web applications, and can be in any consumption pricing plan (including Always On): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure

`Azure Bot Service` bots are function applications.  They should also be provisional within an App Service plan: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale

---

Edit: 
From above documentation: you will need to setup a VM to host an Azure Function as Always On.

**App Service plan**

> In the App Service plan, your function apps run on dedicated VMs on
>   Basic, Standard, and Premium SKUs, similar to Web Apps. Dedicated VMs
>   are allocated to your App Service apps, which means the functions host
>   is always running. Consider an App Service plan in the following
>   cases: You have existing, underutilized VMs that are already running
>   other App Service instances. You expect your function apps to run
>   continuously, or nearly continuously. You need more CPU or memory
>   options than what is provided on the Consumption plan. You need to run
>   longer than the maximum execution time allowed on the Consumption
>   plan. A VM decouples cost from both runtime and memory size. As a
>   result, you won't pay more than the cost of the VM instance that you
>   allocate. For details about how the App Service plan works, see the
>   Azure App Service plans in-depth overview.

Comment: It is an azure bot service application.  I tried creating a test bot using the resource group my other application is running on that is configured to use a basic plan with an S1 type instance.  When I go to save the new bot with that configuration, it gives me this error: The Consumption pricing tier is not allowed in this resource group. Use this link to learn more http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=825764.

Comment: Yeah, there seems to be some holes in the ABS provisioning right now (I can find nowhere to choose App Service plan).

Comment: I suppose I can create a timer based service to poke the bot every 5 minutes or something like that, but it would be awesome to be able to use the existing approach that works in other application types.

Comment: In regard to the latest update, we are not really interested in maintaining a VM and the costs of that for this application, so I don't think that would work in this case.  We moved to the app service model so we could get away from the VMs the old application was running on.  So I guess in this case, we want sort of a mixed approach...